# Querying Hbase using Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am new to Apache Phoenix,

is it possible to query an Hbase table using "regex" in Phoenix. My Apache Phoenix sits on top of Hbase (No MapReduce). For example, I need to query names that start with `Er*`

Paulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do query for regular expression matches in Phoenix. Look into string functions on this page: http://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html

Comment: thanks! Do you also know of any web site with some query examples.

Comment: Phoenix follows ANSI SQL standard wherever possible. So, most of the example for regex search in SQL on internet should work.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can use Apache Phoenix for the regex matches as suggested above. In order to structure your queries kindly follow the grammar page of phoenix at http://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html . Its a concise explanation of how to use phoenix. Kindly go through the hints to be used also on the same page as you can very well optimise ur queries using it.